# Computing $\int_\gamma \overline{f(z)}\ dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

**Background:** My question concerns a calculation involving the integral
$\int_\gamma \overline{f(z)}\ dz$. Consider that if we write
$f = g + ih$ with real-valued functions $g$ and $h$, and similarly
$\gamma = \alpha + i\beta$, we obtain

$$\begin{align}
\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz &= \int_a^b f(\gamma(t))\cdot\gamma'(t)\,dt\\
&= \int_a^b \left(g(\gamma(t)) + ih(\gamma(t))\right)\cdot\left(\alpha'(t) + i\beta'(t)\right)\,dt\\
&= \int_a^b \left(g(\gamma(t))\alpha'(t) - h(\gamma(t))\beta'(t)\right) + i\left(g(\gamma(t))\beta'(t) + h(\gamma(t))\alpha'(t)\right)\,dt\\
&= \int_a^b g(\gamma(t))\alpha'(t) - h(\gamma(t))\beta'(t)\,dt + i \int_a^b g(\gamma(t))\beta'(t) + h(\gamma(t))\alpha'(t)\,dt.
\end{align}$$

**Claim:** In another post ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/734402/understanding-the-definition-of-int-gamma-f-overlinedz)), it was claimed that we obtain

$$\int_\gamma \overline{f(z)}\,dz = \int_a^b g(\gamma(t))\alpha'(t) + h(\gamma(t))\beta'(t)\,dt + i\int_a^b g(\gamma(t))\beta'(t) - h(\gamma(t))\alpha'(t)\,dt.$$

But this seems wrong according to my calculation below. Indeed, it seems
to me that

$$\begin{align}
\int_\gamma \overline{f(z)}\,dz &= \int_a^b \overline{f(\gamma(t))\cdot\gamma'(t)}\,dt\\
&= \int_a^b \overline{\left(g(\gamma(t)) + ih(\gamma(t))\right)\cdot\left(\alpha'(t) + i\beta'(t)\right)}\,dt\\
&= \int_a^b \overline{\left(g(\gamma(t))\alpha'(t) - h(\gamma(t))\beta'(t)\right) + i\left(g(\gamma(t))\beta'(t) + h(\gamma(t))\alpha'(t)\right)}\,dt\\
&= \int_a^b \left(g(\gamma(t))\alpha'(t) - h(\gamma(t))\beta'(t)\right) - i\left(g(\gamma(t))\beta'(t) + h(\gamma(t))\alpha'(t)\right)\,dt\\
&= \int_a^b g(\gamma(t))\alpha'(t) - h(\gamma(t))\beta'(t)\,dt - i \int_a^b g(\gamma(t))\beta'(t) - h(\gamma(t))\alpha'(t)\,dt.\\
&\ne \int_a^b g(\gamma(t))\alpha'(t) + h(\gamma(t))\beta'(t)\,dt + i\int_a^b g(\gamma(t))\beta'(t) - h(\gamma(t))\alpha'(t)\,dt
\end{align}$$

So where did I go wrong in the calculation above?

Comment: You have $$\int_\gamma \overline{f(z)}\,dz = \int_a^b \overline{f(\gamma(t))}\cdot \gamma'(t)\,dt.$$ Only the function $f$ is conjugated, not the differential $dz$ which corresponds to $\gamma'(t)\,dt$. When you write/replace $z = \gamma(t)$, you get $dz = z'(t)\,dt = \gamma'(t)\,dt$.

Comment: OK -- that should help resolve the issue.